# NullReference exception when using LINQ Contains with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a project where I'm converting Linq to SQL (which I admittedly very poorly understand) to Linq to Entity and have ran into an odd situation. The code below correctly returns results when evaluated against a class generated in the Linq to SQL designer but does not work when run against an Entity Framework entity. Specifically if any of the properties in the Or clauses are null, the process breaks with a Null Reference exception. I've tried techniques to check for null property and then say, pass a value I know can't be in the SearchTerm to short circuit around this but they just result in this LINQ returning all results from the entity in a way that I don't really understand either.

```
        Return (From values In Location.getData _
                Where (values.LocName.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Address.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Address2.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.City.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.State.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.QIM.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.MacID.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Phone.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.PrimServ.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Zip.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Area.Contains(SearchTerm) _
                Or values.Type.Contains(SearchTerm)
                ) And (values.Status <> "Closed" Or status_parm = "Closed")
            Select values)
```

As you can probably guess the getData method on the entity class Location is basically using DbContext.SqlQuery to construct a query into the database and then this LINQ is being used to filter the results. I'm aware of several issues with this that make it less than ideal, but there are reasons it was written this way before I started the conversion that aren't easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
Where (values.LocName IsNot Nothing AndAlso values.LocName.Contains(SearchTerm)) OrElse
      (values.Address IsNot Nothing AndAlso values.Address.Contains(SearchTerm))
```

Comment: No, this solution does not work. I have tried several similar techniques to both check the value for null and then evaluate it if it isn't null. All of them either cause the LINQ operation to return all of the results of the query, or none. This solution returns none of the results, with a SearchTerm that works perfectly when this operation is being ran against a Linq to SQL version of "Location" instead of the entity. I'm not understanding how the underlying technologies could require such a different approach that nothing is making this LINQ query work.

Comment: I do think using AndAlso and OrElse is a better practice for this, though. I'm also not very experienced in VB.net (mostly C# in the .NET world) and I actually had forgotten about Or / Else in the VB.net world being different than && and || in C#.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer I finally got working was to use ToLower

```
SearchTerm = SearchTerm.ToLower

Return (From values In Location.getData _
Where (values.LocName IsNot Nothing And Also values.LocName.ToLower.Contains(SearchTerm)
```

I would still like to understand two things:

1. Why is a check for null required when using LINQ to Entity where in LINQ to SQL it runs without issue and never hits a NullReference exception?
2. Why is LINQ's .Contains not case sensitive in LINQ to SQL but it is here? I've verified with 100% certainty this same code using LINQ to SQL does not throw NullReference exceptions ever, and does not require dealing with .Contains as a case sensitive function (so any casing of the SearchTerm will match to any casing of the result implicitly.)